# When I place my doubles on top, the program doesn't run properly

Tags: java, variables

Assignment: Variables
    This program prompts the user to enter a temperature between -58°F and 
        41°F and a wind speed greater than or equal to 2 then displays then 
        displays the wind-chill temperature.

```
// Imports util.Scanner
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Windchill {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Tempurature
    double temperature = input.nextDouble();
    // Windspeed
    double speed = input.nextDouble();
    // Compute the wind chill tempurature
    double windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature -         
                   35.75 * Math.pow(speed, 
                           0.16) + 0.4275 * temperature * 
                           Math.pow(speed, 0.16);

    // Prompt the user to enter a temperature between -58F and 41F.
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit " +
    "between -58\u00b0F and 41\u00b0F: ");

    // Prompt the user to enter the wind speed greter than or equal to 2.
    System.out.print("Enter the wind speed (>= 2) in miles per hour: ");

    // Display result
    System.out.println("The wind chill tempurature is " + windChill);

        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run properly"?  Also, why are you placing your prompts after where you're gathering user input?

Comment: Trying to take input before the user is prompted to type something in is probably not what you want.

Comment: If it doesn't run properly, how does it run? And did you want to ask a question? Also, if it does run properly when you don't "place your doubles on top" - don't place your doubles on top.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a school assignment. However, it seems like you have already completed the bulk of the work. Congratulations! Now, I feel like the issue here can be solved by explaining why your program does not work if "the doubles are on top". I hope that my answer can help you better understand the way java interprets your code!

Without further ado, programming languages of all types have variables. Java is no different. For example...

```
    double number = 0.0; // Java variable declaration
    number = 0.0 # Python variable declaration
    var number = 0.0 // JavaScript variable declaration
```

Your code is going to be executed from the top down. An illustration of this would look like the following.

```
int money = 0;
System.out.println(money);
money = 10;
System.out.println(money);
money = 9000;
System.out.println("I have over " + money);
```

This will output

```
0
10
I have over 9000
```

However, if you wrote this code like the following

```
System.out.println(money);
int money = 0;
```

You will get an error! This is because the execution has not seen that money is even a thing yet! This would be like brushing your teeth without a tooth brush. You can't because you don't have a brush.

Therefore, the same applies to your program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    double temperature = input.nextDouble();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Prompt the user to enter a temperature between -58F and 41F.
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit " +
    "between -58\u00b0F and 41\u00b0F: ");
    // Tempurature

        // Prompt the user to enter the wind speed greter than or equal to 2.
    System.out.print("Enter the wind speed (>= 2) in miles per hour: ");
    // Windspeed
    double speed = input.nextDouble();
    // Compute the wind chill tempurature
    double windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature -         
                   35.75 * Math.pow(speed, 
                           0.16) + 0.4275 * temperature * 
                           Math.pow(speed, 0.16);

        // Display result
    System.out.println("The wind chill tempurature is " + windChill);

}
```

Notice temperature above the scanner line. Input is a object you create to read in that double. If you try to use this before you create your input object the program has no idea what that input object is!

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange the code like below

```
// Imports util.Scanner
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Windchill {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Prompt the user to enter a temperature between -58F and 41F.
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit " +
    "between -58\u00b0F and 41\u00b0F: ");
    // Tempurature
    double temperature = input.nextDouble();
        // Prompt the user to enter the wind speed greter than or equal to 2.
    System.out.print("Enter the wind speed (>= 2) in miles per hour: ");
    // Windspeed
    double speed = input.nextDouble();
    // Compute the wind chill tempurature
    double windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature -         
                   35.75 * Math.pow(speed, 
                           0.16) + 0.4275 * temperature * 
                           Math.pow(speed, 0.16);

    // Display result
    System.out.println("The wind chill tempurature is " + windChill);

        }
}
```

but there is no problem related to double, :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I got it.

/*  Assignment: Variables
    This program prompts the user to enter a temperature between -58°F and 41°F 
    and a wind speed greater than or equal to 2 then displays then displays the 
    wind-chill tempurature.
*/

// Imports util.Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Windchill {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare variables
    double temperature;
    double windspeed;
    double wind_chill;

    // Create a Scanner object to read input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter a temperature between -58F and 41F.
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit " +
                     "between -58\u00b0F and 41\u00b0F: ");
    temperature = input.nextDouble();       

    // Prompt the user to enter the wind speed greter than or equal to 2.
    System.out.print("Enter the wind speed (>= 2) in miles per hour: ");
    windspeed = input.nextDouble();

    // Display result
    wind_chill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature -
               35.75 * Math.pow(windspeed, 0.16) +
               0.4275 * temperature * Math.pow(windspeed, 0.16);

    System.out.println("The wind chill temprature is " + wind_chill);

}
```

}